# Merge/join two dataframes based on index and colum

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

I would like to join (or merge?) two dataframes. They look like the following:

**Table 1 ( = df)**

```
index  |   year  |  country
----------------------------
0      |   1970  | NL
1      |   1970  | UK
2      |   1980  | US
3      |   1990  | NL
4      |   1990  | US
```

**Table 2 (= df_gdp)**

```
cntry  |   1970  |  1980   |   1990
-----------------------------------
NL     |   5     |    3    |   0
UK     |   1     |    7    |   1
US     |   9     |    2    |   0
```

The result should be Table1 with an additional column 'GDP'. The values of Table1.year and Table.country should be used to look up the value in Table2. So the result would be:

```
index  |   year  |  country  | GDP 
--------------------------------------
0      |   1970  | NL        | 5
1      |   1970  | UK        | 1
2      |   1980  | US        | 2
3      |   1990  | NL        | 0
4      |   1990  | US        | 0
```

I already wrote the function with `.iterrows()` but as expected, this does not have a good performance. Instead, I'm wondering whether the result can also be achieved by either `.join()` or `.merge()`. What I do not understand is how to merge/join based on the index (cntry) and a changing column (the year). The code of `.iterrows()`looks like the following:

```
# Add GDP data 
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    gdp_year = str(df.iloc[index].year)
    gdp_country = str(df.iloc[index].country)
    
    try:
        df.at[index, 'GDP'] = df_gdp.loc[gdp_country][gdp_year]
    except:
        df.at[index, 'GDP'] = 0
df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function that takes a dataframe as argument, and apply it to df:

```
def f(x):
    return df_gdp.loc[x['country'],x['year']]

df['GDP']=df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

Result:

```
   year country  GDP
0  1970      NL    5
1  1970      UK    1
2  1980      US    2
3  1990      NL    0
4  1990      US    0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas.DataFrame.merge) as follows.

#### Explanation:

Set index to `country` column and then perform [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) operation so that you can get columns in row. Then you need to [`reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.reset_index) to get dataframe structure similar to df1. After that you need to specify column names using [`set_axis()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html#pandas-dataframe-set-axis) so that you can map it later while performing merge operation.

And at last just perform merge operation on `df1` and preprocessed `df_m` dataframe(default is inner join operation).

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {
    'year':['1970','1970','1980','1990','1990'],
    'country':['NL','UK','US','NL','US']
}

data2 = {
    'country':['NL','UK','US'],
    '1970':[5,1,9],
    '1980':[3,7,2],
    '1990':[0,1,0]
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

# See below code
df_m = df2.set_index('country').stack().reset_index().set_axis(['country', 'year', 'GDP'], axis=1)
pd.merge(df1, df_m, on=['year','country'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `melt` and `merge`:

```
df2.rename({'cntry': 'country'}, axis=1)\
.melt('country', var_name='year', value_name='GDP')\
.merge(df1, on=['country', 'year'])
```

Output:

```
  country  year  GDP
0      NL  1970    5
1      UK  1970    1
2      US  1980    2
3      NL  1990    0
4      US  1990    0
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me.

```
import pandas as pd

valueset_data = {
    'varName': ['ICLEVEL', 'ICLEVEL', 'State', 'State'],
    'codevalue': [1, 2, 1, 2],
    'varLabel': ['Less than 2 years (below associate)', 'Four years', 'MA', 'CT']
}

HD2019_data = {
    'InstituteID': [23, 32],
    'ICLEVEL': [1, 2],
    'State': [2, 1]
}

valueset = pd.DataFrame(valueset_data)
HD2019 = pd.DataFrame(HD2019_data)

valueset_dict = valueset.set_index(['varName', 'codevalue']).to_dict()['varLabel']

HD2019['ICLEVEL'] = HD2019.apply(lambda x: valueset_dict[('ICLEVEL', x['ICLEVEL'])], axis=1)
HD2019['State'] = HD2019.apply(lambda x: valueset_dict[('State', x['State'])], axis=1)

print(HD2019)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please avoid code only answer and provide an explanation. You also could have a look at [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).